# Condition "else" is not allowed? Why?

Tags: if-statement, lua

Why is the `else` statement is not allowed to have a `then` or other conditions?
Is it because it is the final condition within the `else-if` conditions it represents?

I am struggling to understand this concept since I'm a beginner who just learned about variables.

I'm asking this because I received an error with my `else` statement in the code:

```
message = 0
condition = 30

if condition <=10
message = “try harder”

elseif
condition <=20 then
message = "Almost learning"

else
condition = <=30 **—This is the line where I get the error message**
message = "Now you’re getting it"

end
print(message)
```

Would appreciate someone breaking down in laymen terms, why else is not allowed to have `<` or `>` or `then` or other conditions.

Comment: You need `then` after `if condition <=10`. You should have got this error message `lua: 1:5: 'then' expected near 'message'`

Answer (score 2):

```
else condition = <= 30
```

(which is the way your code was originally formatted) would be a *very* unusual feature in a language.

The whole *point* of `else` on its own is to execute if *none* of the other conditions were true. So a condition on the `else` is absolutely useless.

The [Programming in Lua book `if` statement](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html) shows the normal usage:

```
if op == "+" then
  r = a + b
elseif op == "-" then
  r = a - b
elseif op == "*" then
  r = a*b
elseif op == "/" then
  r = a/b
else
  error("invalid operation")
end
```

However, your actual code (when formatted correctly) ends up looking like:

```
else
condition = <=30
```

which is *correct* in terms of the `else` but unfortunately makes the next line a statement. And this statement is very much incorrect syntax.

Now it *may* be that you meant to assign 30 to condition but, based on your other lines (that sort of match this as a condition), I suspect not. So it's probably best just to remove that line totally.

Comment: thank you paxdiablo this lkind of helps me understand better: ‘ The whole point of else on its own is to execute if none of the other conditions were true.       So a condition on the else is absolutely useless.’     (weird I can’t qoute you and I have to type in this weird condensed box) any ways.. how I am registering your response is... pretty much ‘else’ has to be alone. It’s like making your final point in a real world debate.  I think I understand. thank you.